# Java only project not adding dependecies on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dependency-management

I am using Android Studio 0.8.2 and in my project I have one Android module and one Java only module.
The java only module depends on a external library. I have tried adding it in the libs dir of the project:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

And using maven repositories:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0+'
}
```

Both systems allows compilation but the library is not included on final jar. I have unzipped the jar and the classes are not there!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException
```

A Gradle sync shows this warning message:

```
"A top-level `dependencies` block should only appear in build files that correspond to a module"
```

Any idea? Thanks advanced.

Comment: That warning is bogus; see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73939. Oh, wait, I see you've already replied to that bug.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not declaring dependencies in build.gradle in app folder, but in the main roof of project? Am I right? You should compare declaring dependencies with other projects like hmm on github. Example: https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/sample/build.gradle (this is build.gradle file in module project, if you go up to root, in build.gradle file there is not declaring not connected to gradle depenncies). Read carefuly the comments and warnings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have no app folder but two module folders, the dependecies I am declaring for this module are in the java only module folder build.gradle. The root build.gradle does not have dependencies and the Android module add correctly the dependencies defines in its own folder build.gradle.